# Enum does not SET in Api Explorer when in a Serializable class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, serialization, enums, google-cloud-platform

I have the following Enum class

```
public enum EventAccess {
            PUBLIC("PUBLIC"),
            EMPLOYEES_ONLY("EMPLOYEES_ONLY"),

String name;
private EventAccess(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
   }
 }
```

Also i have a Serializable class that that has the enum as one of its fields

```
 public class EventAccessRequest implements Serializable{

private List<EventAccess> event_access = new ArrayList<>();

public EventAccessRequest() {

}

public List<EventAccess> getEvent_access() {
    return event_access;
}

public void setEvent_access(List<EventAccess> event_access) {
    this.event_access = event_access;
  }
}
```

I have an  @Api method that has creates an object the  of type EventAccessRequest. I set the value of this request in the Api Explorer but it does no set any enum field i put in it.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "fetchEventByEventAccess", path = "user/events/list-by-access/", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public RestfulResponse fetchEventByEventAccess(EventAccessRequest request)throws Exception
    {

            EventAccess x = request.getEvent_access().get(0);

            return new RestfulResponse(Status.SUCCESS, "Events retrieved",request, 200);
        }

    }
```

I have tried inserting other types which is not enum and it sets their value but when I try inserting an Enum in Api exploere in does not set the value.
and so my request object is always empty.

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you implement `Serializable` you should provide a [`serialVersionUID`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it).

Comment: @Michael thank you very much, but serialVersionUID does not apper to be the problem I thnik its for verifying if the object has changed

Comment: Yep, that's why I posted a comment and not an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was that you were using the httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET instead of httpMethod = **HttpMethod.POST** since u are sending a pay load request, you will need to make your http method to wait for post request to accept payload or request body

so it should be

```
@ApiMethod(name = "fetchEventByEventAccess", path = "user/events/list-by-access/", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
```

observe the httpMethod thanks.